# Combinatoric question on the size ${n}\choose{n/3}$

Tags: combinatorics

Assume there is a set of $n$ elements $X=\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\}$ And a function $f:{X}\times{X}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. This set satisfies a condition: in each sub set of $A\subset{X}$ with $|A|={n/3}$,there exists $x_{i},x_{j}\in{A}$ with $f(x_{i}, x_{j}) = 1$ ($i\neq{j}$).

Are there always $\Omega(n^{2})$ pairs $(i,j)$ with $f(x_{i}, x_{j})=1$?

No matter how I try to construct the pairing I end up with $\Omega{(n)}$ pairs.

It could be false though, but I can not prove that either.

Answer (score 3):

NO, only $\theta(n)$ pairs is the best you can guarantee.

HINT: Find a graph $G$ on $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\}$ with only $O(n)$ edges that does not have an independent set of size $\frac{n}{3}$. An example would be the graph consisting of $\frac{n}{4}$ vertex-disjoint cliques of $4$ vertices each. Then let $f$ be the function where $f(x_ix_j)$ is $1$ iff $x_ix_j$ form an edge in $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p=C/n$. For large $n$, the maximal independent set in the Erdos-Renyi random graph $G(n,p)$ has size less than $100+4n\log(C)/C $ with high probability, see, e.g. the last page of [1].

Let $f(x_i,x_j)=1$ iff $\{i,j\}$ is an edge of this graph.
Take $C=e^4 \in [54,55]$. Then   with high probability, the total number of edges in $G(n,p)$ is below $30n$.  However, with high probability
there is no independent set of size $n/3$, so the hypothesis on $f$ is satisfied.

[1] https://lucatrevisan.github.io/teaching/bwca17/lectures/lecture02.pdf